# 16.04: Networking UX Inconsistent with WIFI state

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, 16.04, network-manager

```
HW: Bus 003 Device 002: ID 13b1:003f Linksys WUSB6300 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8812AU]
Net:   *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@3:2
       logical name: enxc8d719c1088a
       serial: c8:d7:19:c1:08:8a
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8812au ip=192.168.1.171
       multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11AC
```

This is from 16.04LTS. A few points:

1. The WIFI USB card driver install was flawless.
2. Connecting to my WIFI works as expected.
3. When the system enters into suspend mode, and returns the network interface continues to function as expected.

However, the UX on the desktop has a LAN connection Icon, and as you can see from the screenshot, it doesn't show it as connected to a SSID.

[image]
I'm more concerned about the UX here, and inconsistency, and I don't know where the UX gets the information to update the state.  Where should I start looking, and is this a known issue if not we can forward it to the team to look at it.

Again this is a usability issue, I'm looking at things that may confuse the average non-techie person.  And aside from there, there's a security concern that the user should be made aware of what SSID they are connected on.

Comment: This looks like a bug. Report it to Launchpad.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new I'll look up launchpad, if you have a url to direct please help with that. :)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: Run `ubuntu-bug network-manager` and follow directions.

Answer (score 0):

I've filed here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1598902

I'll track it from here in launchpad.  If there are any work arounds please let me know.